# Can't copy Paste text from window to Ubuntu User

Tags: 20.04

Im pretty noob about Ubuntu. I have a problem could you help me out? please.

I run Ubuntu 20.04 server. Views through Remote desktop.
If I login like root , it is smooth and can copy/paste to ubuntu

I create user with Sudo . When Login as user, It is so lag and can't copy/paste text windows to ubuntu.

How to Do i can fix this? thanks

Comment: Probably bad internet or network.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I run same time both of them ( Root, user ). But Only Root work.

Comment: How are you pasting in Ubuntu - middle click or ctrl v?

Comment: @cup  click mouse, Ctrl+ V, Ctrl+Shift+V... shift+insert,. I have done all. But it paste what I copied on ubuntu, Not what from window

Comment: Which remote desktop - windows RDP or VNC or something else

Comment: I use windows RDP to view Ubuntu. first time login like user sudo, It worked fine. But when second login, it cant paste.